# To open a new web page after pressing the enter key 3 times

Tags: javascript, html

I need the script for functioning the `window.location` only after pressing the ENTER key 3 or n times.

This is my current code and i am trying to modify it. Need help, still.

```
function KeyPress(f) {
            var event = window.event? event : f

            if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                window.location = './index.html';
            
        }

        document.onkeypress = KeyPress;
```

Comment: You should set up the event handler to store each key press in an array and after doing that, check to see if the last 3 entries in the array are the same and are they the ENTER key. If so, you can redirect. **BUT, this seems like a poor UX. You could more easily have a button to press and then follow that up with a confirmation prompt.**

Comment: What's your question? I don't see where you're counting keypresses. You'd also probably want to set a time limit or users will be kicked off to other pages in a seemingly random fashion.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips on how to improve this question.

Answer (score 2):

Following your instructions, after three press to the key ENTER, it should run the code that will call `window.location`. In this example, I'm using `console.log` to prove it is doing what you asking.

*Note: When you run it, you need to click with the mouse where it says "Press Enter 3 times.". In this way, the browser will focus on that section. Then, you can press the ENTER key three times.*

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => enterKeyPressed(e))

let counter = 1;
function enterKeyPressed(event) {
    console.log("Key", event.keyCode, " Pressed:", counter);
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && counter == 3) {
       console.log("Enter key is pressed");
       // window.location = "<url you want to go>";
       return true;
    } 
    counter++;
    return false;    
}
```

```html
Press Enter 3 times. 
Check the log.
```